# Michael Hartl Tutorial, no routes match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes, railstutorial.org

I get this error:

> Failures:
>
> 1) UsersController DELETE 'destroy' should sign a user out
>
> ```
> Failure/Error: delete :destroy
> ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
>   No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"destroy"}
> ```

My test is:

> ```
> it "should sign a user out" do 
>   test_sign_in(Factory(:user))
>   delete :destroy
>   expect(controller).to_not be_signed_in
>   expect(response).to redirect_to(root_path)
> end
> ```

The test_sign_in function is in the spec helper:

> def test_sign_in(user)
>
> ```
>  controller.sign_in(user)
> ```
>
> end

My rake routes:

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
sessions_new GET    /sessions/new(.:format)   sessions#new
   users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
         POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)       sessions#create
new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)   sessions#new
 session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)   sessions#destroy
    root GET    /                         pages#home
 contact GET    /contact(.:format)        pages#contact
   about GET    /about(.:format)          pages#about
    help GET    /help(.:format)           pages#help
  signup GET    /signup(.:format)         users#new
  signin GET    /signin(.:format)         sessions#new
 signout GET    /signout(.:format)        sessions#destroy
pages_home GET    /pages/home(.:format)     pages#home
```

Anyone knows how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

Your route is defined as

```
DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

which means that the route is expecting something like

```
DELETE /users/4
```

Looking at your test, you are just requesting `DELETE /users`, this was derived from this error message:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:controller=>"users", :action=>"destroy"})
```

So, you need to modify your test to handle the `:id` part of the route. This is un-tested, but you're roughly looking for:

```
user = Factory(:user)
test_sign_in(user)
delete :destroy, id: user.id
```

Comment: I did this. I'm getting the following error:   1) UsersController DELETE 'destroy' should sign a user out
     Failure/Error: delete :destroy, id: user.id
     AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
       **The action 'destroy' could not be found for UsersController**   Can you help me with this?

Comment: Actually I was looking at my routes, I'm following the tutorial and I think that **this** is the route I'm trying to use: signout GET    /signout(.:format)        sessions#destroy

Comment: You should be able to just use: `get :signout` in that case. The "The action 'destroy' could not be found for UsersController" error means that inside of your `UsersController` there is no action for `destroy`. This makes sense though, right? Because your `destroy` action lives inside of the `SessionsController`, so you should test the sign out functionality in the spec for the `SessionsController`, not `UsersController`. Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

ooooh god!! I found the error. I accidentally was writing the code in the users_controller_spec and I should do this in the sessions_controller_spec. 
Thanks Andreas for trying to help!

Comment: Sorry, just saw this entry after typing that response!